# sed help: How to print a range of lines ONLY when found within another range of matched lines

Tags: json, sed

I have some input, which you may recognize as a JSON stream, which I need to process from a simple shell script

I've opted to use sed, because half a dozen other manipulations I need to make are already working great with sed.

Below is the scenario.

input1:

```
{
    "Expr": {
        "Criteria": [
            {
               "Values": [
                    {
                        "displayValue": "MyObject",
                        "value": "UUID"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Type": "SELECTED"
    }
}
```

Intended result 1 (print the clause[s] containing displayValue + value pairs}:

```
            {
                "displayValue": "MyObject",
                "value": "UUID"
            }
```

Attempt:

```
$ sed -n -e '/"Expr":/,/"Type": "SELECTED"/ {/"Values":/,/^                    }$/ {/^                    {/,/^                    }/p;};}' /tmp/input1.json
```

Actual result (good):

```
            {
                "displayValue": "MyObject",
                "value": "UUID"
            }
```

Problem is with this input2:

```
{
    "Expr": {
        "Criteria": [
            {
               "Values": [
                    {
                        "displayValue": "MyObject",
                        "value": "UUID"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Type": "NOT_SELECTED"
    }
}
```

Result is unexpected (since outer nest is NOT_SELECTED, do not want match unless SELECTED):

```
$ sed -n -e '/"Expr":/,/"Type": "SELECTED"/ {/"Values":/,/^                    }$/ {/^                    {/,/^                    }/p;};}' /tmp/input2.json
```

Result 2:

```
            {
                "displayValue": "MyObject",
                "value": "UUID"
            }
```

Is it me, or is this a sed bug on my platform?
Otherwise, can you suggest a good approach to this problem?

The constraint is I do not want to print "Criteria" lines that are not within the "Type" is "SELECTED" range.

Comment: This is normal behaviour of the `sed`. If an address range, `/RE1/,/RE2/`, is given, and `RE1` matches a line but `RE2` doesn't match a line following the line that matched the `RE1`, it will match every line from the line that matched the `RE1` to the end of the file. In other words, the second address, `/RE2/`, in an address range means `/RE2/` or the last line, whichever comes first.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Thanks! I understand your explanation. Might there be an option for an explicit match of RE2?  e.g. do not fall through to the inner nesting unless RE2 is an exact match?

Comment: `because half a dozen other manipulations I need to make are already working great with sed` - Agreed, but if you use a proper JSON aware parser like `jq` - you can get a more reliable manipulation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/"Expr"/{:a;n;H;/"Values"/h;/"Type"/!ba;/"SELECTED"/!d;g;s/.*\n((\s*)\{.*\2\}).*/\1/p}' file
```

Use a loop rather than a range.

Form a loop between `"Expr"` and `"Type"` and only proceed if the quoted word `"SELECTED"` is present.

While executing the loop save `Values` in the hold space and then manipulate the saved content to just show the parts needed.

N.B. This is a filtering operation so use the `-n` option.

Comment: Hi, @potong. This is great. Thank you for this. I had to study this and cross reference with a cheat-sheet to even begin to understand it.  I am still struggling with a few of the concepts, but this got me over the hurdle.  To help me better connect the dots, would you have time to answer the inverse question, being what if I needed to delete {
                "displayValue": "MyObject",
                "value": "UUID"
            } including the {}', but only in the range of lines ending in SELECTED. (Otherwise sticking otherwise with the original example).  Thanks again!

Comment: @LeonShaner there is a fine line between filtering and deleting. Using the filtering style `sed -n '/"Expr"/{h;:a;n;H;/"Type"/!ba;g;/"SELECTED"/s/\("Values".*\)\n\s*{[^}]*}/\1/};p' file` notice, the `p` at the end, ensures all lines are printed. Or using the deleting style `sed '/"Expr"/{:a;N;/"Type"/!ba;/"SELECTED"/!b;s/\("Values".*\)\n\s*{[^}]*}/\1/}' file` notice the `-n` is not present and `N` has been swapped for the `n` (also the determination of the chosen lines containing `SELECTED` is throughout all lines collected). The choice is yours as is more refined validation  of values.

Comment: you are awesome! Thanks!  I was on the right track re: d vs p. but unaware of N vs.  I spent hours going through it carefully to no avail, because this area of sed is completely foreign to me. Learning little by little, thanks especially to you.  =D

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `sed` does not look ahead in the file. So, multiline techniques must be used for this job. My approach is to "slurp" lines between toplevel `{` and `}`, which I assume they consist of a single character (`{` or `}`, and no leading and trailing spaces), and examine the resultant pattern space:

```
sed '
/^{$/,/^}$/{
  //!{H;d;}
  g
  s/.*"Values":.*\(\n[[:space:]]*{[^}]*"displayValue":[^}]*"value":[^}]*}\).*"Type":[[:space:]]"SELECTED".*/\1/p
  s/.*//
  h
  d
}' file
```

Comment: Thank you, M. for this. This was harder for me to understand than the other solution, but still very helpful, because as I worked through it, I did learn quite a few things.